# The performance differ .py, .pyc and pyinstaller?

Tags: python, performance

Wondering about performance of python. I produced the code as follow for checking performance on raspberry-pi 3. The python version is 2.7.9.

pslibs/psDebug.py file

```
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime

class CliColor :
    YELLOW ='\x1b[00;033;033m'
    GREEN = '\x1b[00;032;032m'
    RED = '\x1b[00;031;031m'
    NONE = '\x1b[00m'

class PSDebug :
    @staticmethod
    def debug(msg, color=CliColor.NONE) :
        if color == CliColor.NONE :
            print >> sys.stderr, "%s @ %s" % (datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"), msg)
        else :
            print >> sys.stderr, "%s%s @ %s%s" % (color, datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"), msg, CliColor.NONE)

def DBG(arg, color=CliColor.NONE) :
    PSDebug.debug(arg, color)
    sys.stderr.flush()
```

test.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from libps.psDebug import DBG

count = 0
while count <= 10000 :
    DBG('Count : %d' % count)
    count += 1
```

The first, executed 'time ./test.py' in the terminal. It worked and  libps/psDebug.pyc is generated.

The second, deleted libps/psDebug.py and executed 'time ./test.py' with libps/psDebug.pyc.

Third, libps/psDebug.py is restored. run 'pyinstaller test.py' and executed 'time ./test'.

The each result is as follow.

```
real    0m11.946s
user    0m10.130s
sys 0m1.550s

real    0m26.482s
user    0m24.340s
sys 0m1.820s

real    0m20.362s
user    0m18.820s
sys 0m1.010s
```

The predictions in my view point seemed faster in reverse order. But script .py file was more faster. When I'm debugging with strace utility, the only difference things are 'the stat system call error'.

First,'time ./test.py'

```
stat64("/work/temp/libps/psDebug.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=936, ...}) = 0
stat64("/work/temp/libps/psDebug.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=936, ...}) = 0
stat64("/work/temp/libps/psDebug.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=936, ...}) = 0
stat64("/work/temp/libps/psDebug.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=936, ...}) = 0
stat64("./test.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=185, ...}) = 0
stat64("./test.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=185, ...}) = 0
getcwd("/work/temp", 1024)              = 11
stat64("./test.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=185, ...}) = 0
stat64("./test.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=185, ...}) = 0
getcwd("/work/temp", 1024)              = 11
gettimeofday({1463756954, 935083}, NULL) = 0
stat64("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=557, ...}) = 0
write(2, "00:09:14.935083 @ Count : 9999", 30) = 30
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
```

Second,'time ./test.py'

```
stat64("/work/temp/libps/psDebug.py", 0x7e979a40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/work/temp/libps/psDebug.py", 0x7e979980) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/work/temp/libps/psDebug.py", 0x7e979a40) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/work/temp/libps/psDebug.py", 0x7e979980) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("./test.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=185, ...}) = 0
stat64("./test.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=185, ...}) = 0
getcwd("/work/temp", 1024)              = 11
stat64("./test.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=185, ...}) = 0
stat64("./test.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=185, ...}) = 0
getcwd("/work/temp", 1024)              = 11
gettimeofday({1463756850, 285897}, NULL) = 0
stat64("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=557, ...}) = 0
write(2, "00:07:30.285897 @ Count : 9999", 30) = 30
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
```

Third,'time ./test'

```
stat64("libps/psDebug.py", 0x7eac9a10)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or  directory)
getcwd("/work/temp/dist/test", 1024)    = 21
stat64("libps/psDebug.py", 0x7eac9928)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getcwd("/work/temp/dist/test", 1024)    = 21
getcwd("/work/temp/dist/test", 1024)    = 21
stat64("libps/psDebug.py", 0x7eac9858)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("libps/psDebug.py", 0x7eac9a10)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getcwd("/work/temp/dist/test", 1024)    = 21
stat64("libps/psDebug.py", 0x7eac9928)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getcwd("/work/temp/dist/test", 1024)    = 21
getcwd("/work/temp/dist/test", 1024)    = 21
stat64("libps/psDebug.py", 0x7eac9858)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("test.py", 0x7eac9a10)           = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getcwd("/work/temp/dist/test", 1024)    = 21
stat64("test.py", 0x7eac9928)           = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getcwd("/work/temp/dist/test", 1024)    = 21
stat64("test.py", 0x7eac9cb0)           = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getcwd("/work/temp/dist/test", 1024)    = 21
stat64("test.py", 0x7eac9bc8)           = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getcwd("/work/temp/dist/test", 1024)    = 21
gettimeofday({1463756115, 1765}, NULL)  = 0
stat64("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=557, ...}) = 0
write(2, "23:55:15.001765 @ Count : 6912", 30) = 30
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
```

Please, advice how to improve the performance of the second and third methods.

Comment: It checks for the `.py` first, if it can't find it then it checks for the `.pyc`, thats why it is taking longer, why do you need to improve the performance of the other two ways anyway?

Comment: it seems that when you use pyinstaller it is checking relative paths so the (absolute) path `libps/psDebug.py` is checked and doesn't exist so it has to retrieve the current working directory (cwd) and fix the path, where as python interpreter does that much more efficiently.

Comment: I'm just checking what is the way more efficient for use python in the low-performance devices.

Comment: ok, definitely the standard interpreter.  I don't think there is a way to optimize the second case but I'd expect pyinstaller should have a way to increase efficiency, I just don't know what that is...